# Is there a numbering convention for xorg.conf.d files?

Tags: xorg, administration

I have had to set up custom `xorg.conf.d` files on several boxes and one nagging question finally can't be ignored: Is there a numbering convention for these files? Does the number control load priority when read by the Xorg server? Is it like a Dewey decimal system for configuration topics? Or is it simply a convenience feature to allow sysadmins to organize these files however they like?

I tried searching for this topic both here and on the wider Internet, but everything was always in the context of specific configuration topics, not discussions of Xorg in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration files are numbered to impose a sequence on them, e.g. do this one first, then this one, ...

See `man run-parts` for more information.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a reference for how you know that X11 uses run-parts? Where does it call run-parts?

Answer (score 6):

`xorg.conf.d` files are applied in the alphabetical order in the directory.

So these numbers set the order of execution.

This is common for all `*.d` config directories. Like `/udev/rules.d/`, etc.

Comment: What happens when two files match the same device? Does the first handler take precedence, or does the second one overwrite the first?